# Graphical representation of derivatives in higher dimensions than 2D...

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

I know how the derivative of y with respect to x ($\frac{dy}{dx}$)  represents the slope of the the line tangent to the curve at the point with x-coordinate as 'x', in the x-y plane ; this is when we speak of 2D space.

What I wish to know is what these derivatives represent in higher dimensions.

Eg. in 3D, what does the value of $f'(x,y)$ represent?

Take in mind I am still in high school so explain in a reasonably understandable language.

Thanks..

Comment: What is the definition of $f'(x,y)$? Is it $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$?

Comment: Yes I suppose, is there any other thing it could mean?

Comment: The thing is, there are many different things derivative could mean once you leave one dimension. Generally, things always get interesting when you move out of the line. There are partial derivatives, there is the gradient, which may be combined with other objects to give the total differential, the directional derivative along a curve, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say prime notation is a bit out of its depth here. If you are taking the derivative of a multivariate function $f(x,y)$, you would need to specify the variable with respect to which you are differentiating.

For example, letting $f(x,y)=x+y$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=y+1$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=x+1$$
using Leibniz notation. If you haven't seen this notation, the choice of $x$ or $y$ in the denominator of the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ tells the reader that you are not interested in the other variable.  I have never seen the notation $f'(x,y)$ used, and I don't think it would be considered acceptable by most authors. Hope this helps!

P.S. I'm in my final year of high school, so hopefully this isn't hard to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of a function is given by $$\nabla f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}$$
The geometrical interpretation is that this is a vector pointed in the direction where you have the steepest increase. The magnitude is the slope in that direction. See for example the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12763)

Comment: Why would anyone notate $\nabla f(x,y)$ as $f'(x,y)$?

Comment: I don't think anyone would. For me $f'$ makes sense if I have only one variable.

Comment: The author explained in the comments what he really meant.

Comment: Didn't see Allawonder's comment, apologies

Comment: No problem. I think the more important is that you missed the author's comment just before that. He was not aware that you can do other things as well