# Area of sphere intercepted by given curve the given curve.

Tags: calculus, recreational-mathematics, 3d, area

I was just messing around in geogebra 3D, when I noticed a strangely shaped portion of the unit sphere at origin, made by intercepting it with $z = e^{-x^2}$.

[[image: 1]]

[image]

> So I was wondering wether we could calculate the area of the spherical part intercepted, i.e. the pink butterfly-like part shown in the pictures?

[Here is the link to the graph in geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/ucuzn7am)

I cant seem to figure out where to start...... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that this computation is tractable.

Comment: Do you know about surface integrals? Otherwise I don't see how you can do this.

Comment: OP: I'm deleting my answer (at least temporarily) to review it.  Thanks, and sorry for the inconvenience.  ETA: Oops, I can't delete it because you've accepted it, but do be aware that I'm reviewing it.

Comment: No problem @BrianTung

Comment: OP: I figured it out.  See revised answer, and also my last comment to my answer for elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection curve is

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1,\\z=e^{-x^2}$$

and on the $xy$ plane,

$$x^2+e^{-2x^2}+y^2=1$$ or

$$y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-e^{-2x^2}},$$

which is defined for $|x|\le x^*=0.8926433386409\cdots$

Using symmetry, the area of the portion of the sphere so delimited is given by the surface integral

$$4\int_0^{x^*}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2-e^{-2x^2}}}\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dy\,dx.$$

The integration on $y$ is possible, giving

$$\left.\arctan\dfrac y{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\right|_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2-e^{-2x^2}}}=\arctan(e^{x^2}\sqrt{1-x^2-e^{-2x^2}})$$
 but the second on $x$ is hopeless. You will need numerical integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the boundary of the region, projected down to the $x$-$y$ plane, by solving

$$
e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}
$$

Squaring both sides, then isolating $y^2$ on one side, gives us

$$
y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2-e^{-2x^2}}
$$

Those values of $y$ can give you the integrand.  However, rather than use it directly in a three-d surface integral, as suggested by Yves Daoust in the comments below, I will make use of a pretty fact that ought to be better known than it is:

> Suppose you encase a unit sphere in a right cylinder of radius $1$ and height $2$ (so that it exactly circumscribes the sphere).  Then cut any slab of the cylinder and the encased sphere (perpendicular to the cylinder's axis).  The surface area of the sphere slice and the surface area of the cylinder slice are exactly equal.

This is perhaps a bit difficult to visualize if you haven't seen it before, so here's a picture.

[image]

The light blue portions of the surface areas are equal (not the dark blue sections).

What this means, analytically, is that we can first find what angle of the sphere is subtended by this value of $y$ that we computed, and twice that angle (because $y$ goes from the negative square root to the positive square root) is the surface area of the spherical slice in question.  For this purpose, we want the arcsin function (inverse sine).  So our integrand will be $2 \arcsin \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2-e^{-2x^2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Now, what are the limits of this integration?  We need to find the values of $x$ where the integrand shrinks back down to $0$.  That is, we must find $x$ where

$$
1-x^2-e^{-2x^2} = 0
$$

As WolframAlpha [tells us](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+in+1-x%5E2-e%5E%28-2x%5E2%29+%3D+0), this is not answerable in elementary functions (at least, I'm pretty confident it can't be); we must make use of the Lambert W function, and obtain a numerical value:

$$
x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{W\!\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)+2}}{\sqrt2}
  \approx 0.892643
$$

To obtain our area, then, we integrate (numerically) [to obtain](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+2*arcsin%28sqrt%281-x%5E2-exp%28-2x%5E2%29%29%2Fsqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29+dx+from+x+%3D+-0.892643+to+0.892643)

$$
A = \int_{x=-0.892643}^{0.892643} 2 \arcsin \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2-e^{-2x^2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx
  \approx 1.2334
$$

Comment: It seems the OP was just introduced to partial derivatives [a few days ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3629158/26369). They may not have any relevant experience to take things from where you left them. I also think you are missing a $2$.

Comment: OP, please comment on what you might need elaborated on...

Comment: @MarkS.: Thanks for the comment; I had the $2$ in my written notes, but not when I typeset.  Let's see what the OP has to say—I prefer this to be sort of an interactive process...

Comment: What do you mean by this mysterious "integrate *carefully*" ? It is likely that the OP does not know about 3D surface integrals.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yeah, I guess that's pretty opaque.  I'll come back and provide a numerical completion; I suspect (ETA: pretty sure) this can't be integrated with a result in elementary functions.

Comment: As I suspected, you are not computing the area of the surface, but the area of its projection onto $xy$. These are two different things.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: No, I don't think so.  The integrand for the projection would simply be $2\sqrt{1-x^2-e^{-x^2}}$ (and [produces a smaller result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+2*%28sqrt%281-x%5E2-exp%28-2x%5E2%29%29%29+dx+from+x+%3D+-0.892643+to+0.892643)).  The integrand for the surface area is $2\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2-e^{-x^2}}$.

Comment: However, I concede I'm not altogether certain.  If you think there's a specific flaw in my line of argument, could you point it out?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I've figured it out.  This approach works, but I used a somewhat wrong integrand (forgetting a factor of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the argument to the arcsin).  Now our answers agree.  Thanks for your answer; it provided a convenient check!